# Как работает оператор >> в fstream?

Tags: c++

У меня есть небольшая программа, которая считает слова, я знаю как она работает, но не совсем понимаю как именно устроен механизм. Конкретно меня интересует оператор >> в условие while. 
За счет чего происходит движение курсора по тексту и как он определяет, что символы отделены пробелами? Как мне дополнить этот код, что бы пробежаться посимвольно и посчитать пробелы?

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <string>
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main(array<System::String ^> ^args){
    ifstream ifs("text.txt", fstream::binary);  
    if(!ifs) {  
        cout << "No such file." << endl;
        system("pause");
        return 1;
    }
    string word;
    int count = 0;

    while (ifs >> word) {
        count++;     
    }
    cout << "Number of words is " << count << "." << endl;
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Вкратце, для типа string в стандартной библиотеке перегружен оператор:

```
istream& operator>> (istream& is, string& str)
```

Он считывает символы из потока в строку пока не встретит пробельный символ (пробел, табуляцию, перевод строки, может что-то еще).

---

Если же говорить поподробней, то в стандарте сказано, что перегружен оператор

```
template <class charT, class traits, class Allocator>
basic_istream<charT, traits>&
operator>>(basic_istream <сharT, traits>& is,
           basic_string<charT, traits, Allocator>& str);
```

и считывает он пока не:

> isspace(c,is.getloc()) is true for the
> next available input character c.

Если же мы пытаемся считать из пустого потока, то для потока устанавливается `failbit`, и условие `(bool)is` становится ложным, поэтому цикл останавливается.

Если вы хотите посчитать пробелы, можете читать символы из потока посимвольно:

```
char c;
while (ifs >> c) {
  if (c == ' ') {
    ++num_of_spaces;
  }
}
```

Comment: Если проходить посимвольно способом, который вы указали, то пробелы так же не учитываются, с char записываются только символы. Я еще немного покопался  на stack overflow и сделал вот так:
 int space_counter;
 while (getline(ifs, word)) {
  space_counter = count(word.begin(), word.end(), ' ');
 }